# Is it okay to say "Yes, we do" in answer to "Are you having a good time?"

Tags: phrase-requests

How to correctly answer the question "Are you having a good time?"

Imagine a parent coming into a room, in which his 12-year-old son is having his birthday party with his classmates. Kids are really having a good time. So what would be the right answer in that case?

1. Yes, we are.
2. Yes, we do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:** the answer to your edited question is unambiguously ***“yes, we are”***. [Short answers](http://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/frage.htm) use the same auxiliary as the question:

- Are you doing fine? — Yes, we are.
- Do you want some more tea? — Yes, I do.
- Will you marry me? — Yes, I will.
- Can I go to the swimming pool, daddy? — No, you can't.

---

It's not exactly clear what you are uncertain about, so I'll try and do my best. There is nothing specific to “having a good time in this question”. To the question “Are you playing with [LEGO](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/300/regdwight)?”, the kids might answer “Yes, we are” (akin to your choice #1) or “Yes, with the big castle” (somewhat closer to #2), or plenty of other things. All are legitimate answers, as are the ones you propose in your question.

Comment: oops, I am sorry. I've just edited my question.

Comment: Your LEGO link leads to RegDwight's page! :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please, tell me why you gave me a link to RegDwight's page. Was it a mistake or you meant something by it?

Comment: Brilliant!